# Provide the correct data type in the generated parameterized dynamic sql (Entity Framework 6)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm using Entity Framework 6, Database First Approach, and I'm looking for a way to provide the correct data type in the generated sql. Specifically change varchar(8000) to varchar(3) in the generated sql.

In my linq I have something like...

```
(from item in entities.Item
 where item.ID.Equals(id)...
```

And the generated parameterized dynamic sql for the ID ....

```
',N'@p__linq__0 varchar(8000).
```

Also, the ID above is a varchar(3) in the database.

And the ID property in the edmx....

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use DataAnnotations "MaxLength" in your class on the field you want to limit.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace yourNamespace
{
        public class Item
        {
            [MaxLength(100)]
            public String id { get; set; }
        }
}
```

Comment: Just tried it and still outputs as varchar(8000)... am i missing something else?

Comment: Ok, then.., this will set the size of the field in the database. I'm afraid I don't know how to make entity framework more smart about field size elsewhere. I will simply delete the answer once it's get downvoted.